# How to wrap elements with new class and remove inner wrapper?

Tags: jquery

For example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"><p>Hello</p></div>
  <div class="inner"><p>Goodbye</p></div>
</div>
```

The output should be like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="new">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Goodbye</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) to wrap all inner wrapper and use [unwrap](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) by using [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to remove the inner wrapper like the following:

Use like this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mLAzd/)

```
$('.inner').wrapAll('<div class="new" />').contents().unwrap();
```

Or use like this: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mLAzd/1/)

```
$('.inner p').unwrap().wrapAll('<div class="new" />');
```

Comment: @Ahmad you have mistakenly edited my answer and changed inner to container and people almost about to downvote. Be aware when editing the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.unwrap()` and `.wrapAll()` methods:

```
$('.container p').unwrap().wrapAll('<div class="new"></div>');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gtT7/)